# Metaclass "TypeError: Config_setup.__init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Tags: python, metaclass

I faced the following error:

```
  in <module>
    class Config(metaclass=Config_setup):
TypeError: Config_setup.__init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I don't know how to resolve it. Can anyone give me an idea please? Thanks!
Here is the code from `"Crowd_flow_prediction"`,

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import platform

class Config_setup(object):
    """docstring for Config"""
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Config_setup, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            cls._instances[cls].__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

    def __init__(self, DATAPATH=None):
        super(Config, self).__init__()

        if DATAPATH is None:
            DATAPATH = os.environ.get('DATAPATH')
            if DATAPATH is None:
                if platform.system() == "Windows" or platform.system() == "Linux":
                    # DATAPATH = "D:/data/traffic_flow"
                # elif platform.system() == "Linux":
                    DATAPATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../../..', 'data')
                else:
                    print("Unsupported/Unknown OS: ", platform.system, "please set DATAPATH")
        self.DATAPATH = DATAPATH
        
class Config(metaclass=Config_setup):
    pass
```

I dont know much about Python

Comment: you are not showing us all the relevant code

Comment: @drum What's missing? For me, it's actually too much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for tips like making a [mre]. A lot of this code seems to be irrelevant to the problem, like to start, `os` and `platform` are definitely not required for a problem with OOP. You can copy the minimal example from my answer if you think it exemplifies your problem well; one way to confirm is to apply the same changes to your code and check that it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) need to take arguments `name, bases, namespace` and should inherit from `type`, not `object`.

As well, `super(Config, self)` won't work since `Config` is not defined at that point. It looks like you want simply `super()` instead, since you're just using it to ["refer to parent classes without naming them explicitly"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super). (This wouldn't work in Python 2, but since Python 2 is EOL, I'm assuming you're not using it.)

Here's a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
class Meta(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Config(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

c = Config()
print(c)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File tmp.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Config(metaclass=Meta):
TypeError: Meta.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

Fix:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, namespace):
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.Config object at 0x7fb20a9b0850>
```